# How to make timer work even if app is closed in swift

Tags: swift, timer, background

I am very new to swift programming and I have an idea to make an app that shows you a new image every time the timer is done. I have already added Background mode and in the background, the app works well. But when I close it, the timer resets. How can I fix it and what is the easiest way to make the timer work even if I will close the app??
Here is my code:

```
var timer: Timer?
var timeLeft = 10 
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
  return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}



func printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds:Int) -> () {
    let (h, m, s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds: timeLeft)
    timeLabel.text = ("\(h) :  \(m) :  \(s) ")
} 



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   
}

@objc func onTimerFires() {
    timeLeft -= 1 
    printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: timeLeft)
 print(timeLeft)    //ПРИНТ
    if timeLeft <= 0 {
        calendarRaven0() 
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
 

func calendarRaven0(){ 
    if timeLeft == 0 {
    timeLabel.text = "Done"
}
    



@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    checkTimerAvaible()
    func checkTimerAvaible(){
    if timeLeft == 0 {
    timeLeft = 10
    viewDidLoad()
        let imageArray =  [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "3") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "4") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "2")]
        mainImages.image = imageArray[Int.random(in: 0...2)]
       
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "close the app"? Obviously when the app exits your code will stop running.

Comment: You can use UserDefaults to store the state of your app between executions.